# How To: stagger SignalR Clients.Others.[function] calls in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, signalr, async-await

I have a basic function that looks like this:

```
public void AllDataUpdated()
{
    Clients.Others.allDataUpdated();
}
```

Now, I want to add a half-second delay between each of these calls. But, I don't want to just lock my web-server up in doing so.

My first instinct was to do the following:

```
async Task SendWithDelay(var other, var timeout)
{
    await Task.Delay(timeout);
    other.allDataUpdated();
}
```

and iterate over each other in my `public void AllDataUpdated()` function and increment the timeout for each iteration. Is this the correct approach? How should I do this in a manner that will not lock-up my webserver with this process, but will stagger the SignalR emits?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** My desired result is that client_0 gets this message at 0ms, then client_1 gets the message at 500ms, etc. All from the same call to `AllDataUpdated()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// synchronization primitive
private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
// the timer for 500 miliseconds delay
private Timer notificator;

// public function used for notification with delay
public void NotifyAllDataUpdatedWithDelay() {
    // first, we need claim lock, because of accessing from multiple threads
    lock(this.syncRoot) {
        if (null == notificator) {
            // notification timer is lazy-loaded
            notificator = new Timer(500);
            notificator.Elapse += notificator_Elapsed;
        }

        if (false == notificator.Enabled) {
            // timer is not enabled (=no notification is in delay)
            // enabling = starting the timer
            notificator.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
private void notificator_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    // first, we need claim lock, because of accessing from multiple threads
    lock(this.syncRoot) {
        // stop the notificator
        notificator.Enabled = false;
    }
    // notify clients
    Clients.Others.allDataUpdated();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code example, but won't this send `allDataUpdated();` to all clients at once? My desired result is that client_0 gets this message at 0ms, then client_1 gets the message at 500ms, etc.

Comment: So, if you have 100 clients, the last client will get notification after 50 seconds?

Comment: Yes, that is the desired behavior. The time interval might change, but we want the notifications to be staggered.